# Differences of SSH jump host vs iptables PREROUTING DNAT

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, iptables

I'm running a server behind a firewall which I do not have control over, hence I'm unable to open ports to access the server from "outside". To solve this, I rented a VPS, and connected the server and the VPS via Wireguard.

To connect to the server from the outside world, I have two options.

1. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth+ -p tcp --dport 19999 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.13.10.2:22`
2. Using the VPS's SSH as a jump host aka `ssh -J vps 10.13.10.2`

Both are working solutions to the problem, but is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Aside from the obvious of needing to be able to SSH into the VPS?

Comment: Yes, that is implied by the fact that I run the server and rented the VPS, I have SSH access to both. Anything other than that?